# Is this "either or" the same as "whether or?

Tags: grammar

Without intelligence, either one's own or another's, true life is impossible.[Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/eso/aww/aww13.htm)

either ones own or another's is the same as "whether one's own or another's?

Comment: If you're reading that text because you're interested in the subject matter that's fine, but I think it's worth pointing out that it is *not representative of normal English*, either written or spoken, formal or informal.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "whether" would have the same effect as "either." In both cases, the message would be that the statement is true if applied to one's own intelligence, and is also true if applied to another's intelligence.

We would not, however, use "whether or" as an answer to a question of options, as we sometimes do with "either or." For example, if asked: "Do you want the yellow one or the blue one," if you do not care which color you get, you could respond "either or." This is not the case with "whether or."